# How to prevent error with quotation marks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I´m sending my data through a JavaScript like this:

```
function: enviaEditar('.$row->id.',\' '.$row->nombre.' \')'
```

As you can see I'm using /' in order to seen a string (text) but I have an error if the value of $row->nombre contain ' or ". Is there a way to prevent both of them.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo '
    <tr style="font-size:12px">
        <td>'.$row->nombre.'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".ModalEditar" onclick="enviaEditar('.$row->id.',\''.$row->nombre.'\');">
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: javascript does not have multi linestrings nor do html attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to url encode the PHP code. Change the line to this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".ModalEditar" onclick="enviaEditar('.urlencode( $row->id ) .',\''. urlencode( $row->nombre ) .'\');">
```